# Extract html tags' attributes

Tags: awk

I'm looking for the easiest way **with awk** to parse this HTML snippet:

```
<a id=1 data1="sth11" data2="sth12" data3="sth13 "><div class="cl1"></div></a> ;
<a id=2 data1="sth21" data2="sth22" data3=" sth23"><div class="cl2"></div></a>   ;
<a id=2 data1="sth31" data3="  sth33  " data2="sth32" ><div class="cl3"></div></a>  ;
```

Into this (concatenation of data3 attributes and separate them with `;`):

```
sth13;sth23;sth33;
```

I tried to browse awk's guides but it seems too huge and although this seems a simple problem, I still haven't found the perfect solution yet.

Would be great to have the solution along with explanation *and* some source if I need something else or similar to spare asking every time.

I've tried a simple one but this one is not good, as field is fixed thus not concatenating the `;` and also not trimming the spaces:

`cat data | awk -F'"' '/data3=/{print $6}'`

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `awk` is like the number 42.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info has resources for learning `awk`.. though, I'd suggest to use a tool like `xmlstarlet`, `xpath`, `dasel`, etc for this problem...

Comment: Thank you, I'd have to *stick* with awk due to platform limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column number isn't fixed (just noticed that OP's input has data2/data3 switched for last line):

```sh
$ awk -v ORS=';' 'match($0, /data3="[^"]+"/){
                  m = substr($0, RSTART+7, RLENGTH-8);
                  gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", m); print m}' ip.txt 
sth13;sth23;sth33;
```

- `-v ORS=';'` will change output record separator to `;` instead of newline
- `match($0, /data3="[^"]+"/)` will match a line containing `data3="` followed non `"` characters and a `"` character
- `m = substr($0, RSTART+7, RLENGTH-8)` will extract the matched portion, minus `data3="` and the last `"` character
- `gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", m)` will remove spaces from start/end of the string in `m`

Modifying F. Knorr's solution:

```sh
awk -F'data3=" *' -v ORS=';' 'NF>1{sub(/ *".*/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

- `-F'data3=" *'` will use `data3="` followed by optional spaces as field separator
- `NF>1` will make sure only a line containing `data3="` is selected
- `sub(/ *".*/, "", $2)` will remove optional space and remaining characters from the line

For multiple matches:

```sh
awk -F'data3=" *' -v ORS=';' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){sub(/ *".*/, "", $i); print $i}}'
```

Comment: If one line can contain multiple `data3=` fields, is there any option to ask `awk` to continue parsing after first match?

Comment: it's possible, but if you have `grep -P`, karakfa's solution is better suited

Comment: How is it possible? In case `grep -P` might not an option

Answer (score 1):

First, I would strongly advise against using for XML-processing. There are better tools out there.

For the example you have provided this command would probably yield the desired output:

```
awk -F 'data3="|>' 'BEGIN{ORS=";"}{sub(/^ +/,"",$2); sub(/[ "].*/,"",$2); print $2}' file
```

Output:

```
sth13;sth23;sth33;
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?gist=192c1bf336fbf175ab1c143d5f92e50f

Comment: Thx. If there is no `data3` field, it gives wrong result, although this was not mentioned in the original question. Also, if the field contains `-`, it goes wrong (like `data-field-3`) Otherwise I like this solution as it's easy and probably very fast.

Answer (score 0):

AS others have suggested, a dedicated html/xml parser would be the best solution for this but if you cannot use one, you can try the following GNU awk solution:

```
awk -F '[ >]' '{ gsub("data3=\"[[:space:]]+","data3=\"",$0);gsub("[[:space:]]+\"","\"",$0);for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /data3/) { split($i,map,"=");gsub("\"","",map[2]);printf "%s;",map[2] } } }' file
```

Explantion:

```
awk -F '[ >]' '{                                                          # Set the field delimiter to space or ">"
                 gsub("data3=\"[[:space:]]+","data3=\"",$0);              # Remove any space in the data3 element definition
                 gsub("[[:space:]]+\"","\"",$0);
                 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
                   if ($i ~ /data3/) { 
                     split($i,map,"=");                                    # Loop through each field and process is it if it contains data3, split the field in the array map using "=" as the delimiter
                     gsub("\"","",map[2]);                                 # Remove quotes from the the second index of map
                     printf "%s;",map[2]                                   # Print the result
                   } 
                  } 
                 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=data3=")[^"]*(?=")' file | 
  sed -E 's/^ +//;s/ +$//'               | 
  paste -sd';'

sth13;sth23;sth33
```

extract quoted string next to `data3=`; trim extra whitespace; concatenate the results.

Comment: you can use `grep -oP 'data3="\h*\K.*?(?=\h*")'` to avoid `sed`

Comment: @Sundeep, thx, standard lookbehind doesn't support variable length assertions. Trying to avoid `perl` specifics. Otherwise, just use `perl` instead.